# Preview doesn't show up (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer)

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, video-capture

I'm trying to first just get my app to show the camera preview of the wide angle camera.
But what I do it just doesn't show up. (the app has video and audio permission and is being tested on an iPhone 7 Plus)

Here's my session configuration code:

```
func configureSession() throws {
    session.beginConfiguration()

    // configure inputs
    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
    let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInMicrophone, for: .audio, position: .unspecified)
    guard let videoInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!), let audioInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!), session.canAddInput(videoInput), session.canAddInput(audioInput) else {
        throw CameraError.configurationFailed
    }

    // configure outputs
    let output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    let previewOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    previewOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    previewOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
    guard session.canAddOutput(output) && session.canAddOutput(previewOutput) else {
        throw CameraError.configurationFailed
    }
    session.sessionPreset = .high
    session.addOutput(output)
    session.addOutput(previewOutput)

    session.commitConfiguration()
}
```

and this is the code for the `previewLayer`:

```
// adds given view as previewView to the session
func configureAsPreview(_ view: UIView) {
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.frame = view.layer.frame
}
```

and it is being called in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if cameraManager.hasPermissionForVideo {
        try! cameraManager.configureSession()
        cameraManager.configureAsPreview(self.previewView)
        cameraManager.startSession()
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "presentPermissions", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
I really can't figure it out and it's probably just something stupidly small.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try update layer frame when needed, and use `bounds` instead of `frame`. Layers dont support autoresizing, you need to manage it manually.

```
private var __previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? = nil
func configureAsPreview(_ view: UIView) {
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.__previewLayer = previewLayer
}

override viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.__previewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Comment: What is this new __previewLayer variable for?

Comment: @Bruce you need to keep reference to that specific layer to have access to it to be able resize it when UIView containing it changes geometry. When viewDidLoad() is invoket is does not mean, that it already has geometry for being shown.